# Filtro usando valor calculado não funciona no Django

Tags: sql, sqlite, django

Tenho um modelo no Django com campos `largura` e `comprimento`, e gostaria de filtrá-lo por área:

```
class Projeto(models.Model):
    largura = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=0, max_digits=4, default=0)
    comprimento = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=0, max_digits=4, default=0)
```

Tentei a seguinte query:

```
Projeto.objects.annotate(area=F('largura')*F('comprimento')).filter(area__lte=1000)
```

Entretanto, não funcionou: a query retornou *todas* as linhas de `Projeto`, inclusive aquelas que tem área maior que `1000`. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Verifiquei o SQL que estava sendo gerado pela query (formatado para legibilidade):

```
>>> print Projeto.objects.annotate(area=F('largura')*F('comprimento')).filter(area__lte=1000).query
SELECT "mcve_projeto"."id", "mcve_projeto"."largura", "mcve_projeto"."comprimento",
       ("mcve_projeto"."largura" * "mcve_projeto"."comprimento") AS "area"
FROM "mcve_projeto"
WHERE ("mcve_projeto"."largura" * "mcve_projeto"."comprimento") <= 1000
```

bem como o SQL de criação do banco (idem):

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate mcve 0001
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "mcve_projeto" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "largura" decimal NOT NULL,
    "comprimento" decimal NOT NULL);

COMMIT;
```

e criei [um exemplo no SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/6a018a/1/0) (nota: estou usando SQLite). Funcionou normal. Onde pode estar o problema?

Comment: Um amigo meu não tem conta no SO, então vou falar aqui uma possível solução que ele falou que poderia dar certo:

`Projeto.objects.annotate(area=F('largura')*F('comprimento')).filter(area__lte=1000).values('area')`

Comment: @mazulo Valeu a sugestão, mas: 1) não funcionou, continuou retornando áreas maiores que 1000; 2) eu quero os objetos completos, não só a área, por isso usar `values` não é uma boa opção pra mim.

Comment: Qual a versão do Django você está usando?

Comment: @mazulo 1.9 no Linux e 1.8 no Windows. Mesmo resultado em ambos. Python 2.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parabéns, você achou um bug no driver do Django pro SQLite!

Reproduzi seu cenário e tive o mesmo comportamento:

```
./manage.py shell
Python 3.4.1 (default, Sep 24 2015, 20:41:10) 
[GCC 4.9.2 20150212 (Red Hat 4.9.2-6)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from area.models import Projeto
>>> for i in Projeto.objects.all(): print(i.largura, i.comprimento, i.largura*i.comprimento)
... 
10 10 100
5 5 25
50 50 2500
101 100 10100
250 250 62500
>>> from django.db.models import F
>>> for i in Projeto.objects.annotate(area=F('largura')*F('comprimento')).filter(area__lte=1000): print(i.largura, i.comprimento)
... 
10 10
5 5
50 50
101 100
250 250
>>>
```

Inicialmente achei que o problema era o SQLite em sí, mas esse teste mostrou que ele está OK:

```
$ sqlite3 db.sqlite3
SQLite version 3.8.11.1 2015-07-29 20:00:57
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> 
sqlite> 
sqlite> select * from area_projeto;
1|10|10
2|5|5
3|50|50
4|101|100
5|250|250
sqlite> SELECT area_projeto.id, area_projeto.largura, area_projeto.comprimento, (area_projeto.largura * area_projeto.comprimento) AS area FROM area_projeto WHERE (area_projeto.largura * area_projeto.comprimento) <= 1000;
1|10|10|100
2|5|5|25
sqlite>
```

Então, pra ter certeza, levei seu problema pro PostgreSQL 9, e ele funcionou perfeitamente:

```
$ ./manage.py shell
Python 3.4.1 (default, Sep 24 2015, 20:41:10) 
[GCC 4.9.2 20150212 (Red Hat 4.9.2-6)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from area.models import Projeto
>>> for i in Projeto.objects.all(): print(i.largura, i.comprimento, i.largura*i.comprimento)
... 
10 10 100
5 5 25
50 50 2500
100 100 10000
250 250 62500
>>> from django.db.models import F
>>> for i in Projeto.objects.annotate(area=F('largura')*F('comprimento')).filter(area__lte=1000): print(i.largura, i.comprimento)
... 
10 10
5 5
>>>
```

Ah, não se esqueça de abrir um Bug Report pros caras!